# Test project within a current project

Tags: java, android, testing, junit

I Have tried to create a test project for my android project, according to Android Developer it should be placed within the project you want to test. I have read all the posts with related problems but can't seem to make it work.

When I create the test project I do not choose the default location, instead I put it in the project folder called "projectnameTest". This works fine at first, except that a new folder is created called "projectnameTestTest". In this new folder all the folders, java files and values are represented, except from gen-->R.java that somehow does not contain all the instances. Also "projectnameTest"-folder is emptied, although if I remove it, the "projectnameTestTest" folder is removed also.

What I'd like to know: 
1. What is the reason for this problem and how is it solved?
2. Could the problem be Git related? (We use GitHub to share all the files)

Appreciate any help possible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the test project via this command:

```
cd workspace/main_project/test_project
android create test-project -m .. -n TestApplicationName -p .
```

and then you can build the project and test it via this command:

```
cd workspace/main_project/test_project
ant clean debug install test
```